# Deploy with capistrano error: …/REVISION No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, web-deployment

I'm using the gem Capistrano ~2.15.5 and deploying my application to my remote server. Everything works fine until the end of the **cap prod deploy** command. I'm receiving this error:

```
** [52.74.34.196 :: out] /bin/bash: ebs/apps/CloudTrendz/releases/20150318203140/REVISION: No such file or directory
** [52.74.34.196 :: out]
command finished in 4923ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf ebs/apps/CloudTrendz/releases/20150318203140; true"
servers: ["52.74.34.196"]
[52.74.34.196] executing command
command finished in 411ms
failed: "/bin/bash --login -c 'git clone -b master git@github.com:prashant4224/CloudTrendz.git ebs/apps/CloudTrendz/releases/20150318203140 && cd ebs/apps/CloudTrendz/releases/20150318203140 && git checkout -b deploy 16cc51ebe1acd97cb489f10313d85f7ae9a69f6b && rm -Rf ebs/apps/CloudTrendz/releases/20150318203140/.git && (echo 16cc51ebe1acd97cb489f10313d85f7ae9a69f6b > ebs/apps/CloudTrendz/releases/20150318203140/REVISION)'" on 52.74.34.196
```

Here deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :application, "CloudTrendz"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:prashant4224/CloudTrendz.git"
set :deploy_to,  "ebs/apps/#{application}"
set :applicationdir,  "ebs/apps/#{application}"

set :scm, :git  # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names

set :branch, "master"


set :deploy_to, applicationdir
set :deploy_via, :export
set :scm_verbose, true

set :user, "ubuntu"
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"

set :keep_releases, 2
set :precompile_only_if_changed, true

default_run_options[:pty] = true
default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash --login'

ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/prashantec2.pem)

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:copy_configs"


task :prod do
 set :domain, "52.74.34.196"
 set :repository, "git@github.com:prashant4224/CloudTrendz.git"
 set :local_repository, "git@github.com:prashant4224/CloudTrendz.git"
 set :branch, "master"
 set :scm_verbose, true
 server "52.74.34.196", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
 set :deploy_env, "prod"
 "deploy"
end

namespace :deploy do

 task :copy_configs, :roles => :app do
   run "cp #{release_path}/../../shared/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
 end

 task :migrate, :roles => :app do
   run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec rake db:migrate"
 end

 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do

  run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path, 'tmp', 'restart.txt')}"
  if deploy_env == 'prod'
    tag_name = Time.now.strftime("deploy_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")

    system "git tag -a -m 'Deployment on prod' #{tag_name}"

    system "git push origin #{tag_name}"
    if $? != 0
      raise "Pushing tag to origin failed"
    end
   end
 end

 namespace :assets do
   task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
   end
 end

end

after "deploy:update", "deploy:migrate", "deploy:cleanup"
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is failing when cloning the git repository from Github.  Make sure that you've added the remote server's SSH key to the Github repository.

You can verify if this is the problem by SSH'ing into the remote server and attempting to run:

```
git clone git@github.com:prashant4224/CloudTrendz.git
```

If this fails, copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and then go to `https://github.com/prashant4224/CloudTrendz/settings/keys`, click "Add deploy key" and paste it in.

If `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` does not exist on the remote server, run `ssh-keygen` to create it.

Comment: Are you able to clone the repository manually from the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I can able to clone the repository manually on remote server @infused

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836635/rails-capistrano-deploy-revision-no-such-file-or-directory.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: I solved the above error by modifying the path `set :applicationdir,  "/home/ubuntu/ebs/apps/#{application}" ` @infused, Thanks