# https://example.com (SSL Error, Host example.com not found in certificate

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-web-services, newrelic

I followed the [Newrelic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/getting-started/new-relic-php)) documentation and installed on my aws server and using `apache` as web server.
Newrelic showing `https://example.com (SSL Error, Host example.com not found in certificate (ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal))`

Any help appreciated

Comment: Where do you see that error? In a newrelic console page, or in a log? What are your `newrelic.ini`/`newrelic.cfg` settings? Also, I see you have many previous questions without an accepted answer ( [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132472/deploy-with-capistrano-error-revision-no-such-file-or-directory) ), which makes me wonder if you'll accept an answer to this question.

Comment: @tedder42 It's on newrelic console page

Comment: In `newrelic.ini` file, I updated only `licence key`